# are line breaks possible in esc_html_e()?

Tags: php, wordpress, line-breaks

I am using the following code:

```
<p><?php esc_html_e( 'It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the navigation links above or a search? Or it is possible you are trying to access a restricted page without being logged in to gain access.', 'shapely' ); ?></p>
```

Which ends up being displayed as follows:

> It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try one of the navigation links above or a search? Or it is possible you are
>   trying to access a restricted page without being logged in to gain
>   access.

What I want to display is this:

> It looks like nothing was found at this location.
>
> Maybe try one of the navigation links above or a search?
>
> Or it is possible you are trying to access a restricted page without
>   being logged in to gain access.

So what I want is a way to break the line.  I tried `<br />` and `\n`, and neither work.  Is there a way to add line breaks in the `esc_html_e()` function?

Comment: Have you tried using `<br>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off you can't use `\n` inside single quotes.  Also, line breaks won't be rendered as such on on a webpage.  From the looks of things `esc_html_e()` actually echoes the output so to capture & process it you'd need to do something like this:

```
ob_start();
esc_html_e("Line1\nLine2\nLine3");
$output = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
echo nl2br($output);
```

But this seems like an awful lot to go through and probably the wrong way to go about it.  If you need to output html you probably don't be using `esc_html_e()` to begin with.  Really hard to say without more context.

Comment: is this correct: `<?php nl2br(esc_html_e("Line1.\n Line2.\n Line 3.", "shapely" )); ?>`  It doesn't appear to work.  This is a WordPress Shapely template 404 page.. so I am not sure if the 2nd parameter "shapely" is necessary for esc_html_e function to work?  I am also not sure why this function is even necessary, as I am controlling the content on the page (ie: static not dynamic!!)

Comment: @SunnyOz - Sorry I just looked at the source for `esc_html_e()` and realized it's actually echoing the output.  See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  It is good to know for future use.. but I think you are right.. that it is a lot of effort to go through.. and I don't see the point for this code, since the display is static.  I think I will just go ahead and change the template to use plain html.

Comment: I'm not a wordpress developer but it looks to me like a glorified version of php's native `htmlentities()` - probably used in themes for echoing user input or where you'd like to actually display html on the page without parsing it.  If the thing you want to display contains static html that you need to actually render and there's no security issue, just `echo` it.

Answer (score 3):

I know this a older question, I wanted to to point out that there is no need to use the output buffering functions in PHP. You can simplify this code by calling the WordPress function esc_html__() instead of esc_html_e(). This function will return the escaped value instead of echoing it out.

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/esc_html__/

```
echo nl2br( esc_html__("Line1\nLine2\nLine3", 'shapely') );
```